# Antialias and jagged edges on Cycles passes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes, antialiasing

I want to composite different passes in Photoshop but the GlossDir pass has jagged edges. I tried to boost samples, different experiments, boost resolution (about 6000x4800) but the GlossDir every time is not usable. I attach an image, can I extract an alpha pass to use in photoshop to mask the GlossDir and obtain e clean pass? (hope you understand my text)
[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the jagged parts are sticking out, then yes you should be able to, in Photoshop, select the alpha channel of your Combined Transparency image and then use that selection to create a mask for your Glossy Direct pass... but you shouldn't have to resort to that. There should be a way to fix it within Blender. Can you post the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Sure! This is the link :
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4381" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4381/)
I removed the hdri due to the file dimension: I tried with another Hdri, the problem is the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to create a new scene, added a simple sphere, an hdri and the glossDir (glossind same) is jagged and seems without antialias..I think I'm doing something wrong :/

Comment: I opened your file and took a quick look. I didn't have a lot of time to spend on it then, but I did notice at least one missing texture (for the environment).

Comment: Yes, I had to remove the hdri due to the file dimension (max 40mb), but there is the problem with any hdri (I try another one just for test). Thanks again!

Comment: @Mentalist I'm really start to thing that is only a problem of antialias that I didn't understand yet. I created a new scene , insert a sphere without any gloss (a simple material principled, roughness 1). Combined pass, perfect, Ao perfect, DiffDir, GlossDir with jagged edge, no antialias from what I can see.